# ¿Cómo actualizo todos los paquetes pip de golpe?

Tags: python, update, pip

me gustaría saber si hay una forma de actualizar todos los paquetes pip con un comando semejante a: $pkg upgrade o $apt update. Lamento que esta pregunta parezca o sea muy básica. Gracias por responder. Saludos.

Comment: Puede parecer una "solución" tonta pero, si te creas un `venv`y abres un proyecto en el que tengas esas librerías, generalmente puede que tengas problemas al instalar los `requirements` al ser versiones más antiguas, con lo que sabrás cuales hay por updatear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A la fecha, no, no hay una manera "natural" de hacerlo, de hecho, hay un [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4551) para agregar esta funcionalidad al comando. Eso sí, hay variadas posibilidades para lograr lo que buscas, [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720014/how-to-upgrade-all-python-packages-with-pip) compila una gran variedad de alternativas, de las cuales destacaría:

#### En Linux o entornos emulados tipo Cygwin (by [rdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158773/rbp))

```
pip list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

o para versiones antiguas de `pip`

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

#### Con código Pyhton, compatible en todos los sistemas operativos (by [Ramana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515656/ramana))

Atención: esta forma no deja ver cualquier `warning`que emita `pip`

Para `pip < 10.0.1`

```
import pip
from subprocess import call

packages = [dist.project_name for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions()]
call("pip install --upgrade " + ' '.join(packages), shell=True)
```

Para `pip >= 10.0.1`

```
import pkg_resources
from subprocess import call

packages = [dist.project_name for dist in pkg_resources.working_set]
call("pip install --upgrade " + ' '.join(packages), shell=True)
```